# using Environment.CurrentDirectory as db storage directory

Tags: c#, .net

If this example using  Environment.CurrentDirectory directory as storage folder like

```
private static string DbFile
{
    get { return Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\MyDb.sqlite"; }
}
```

where exactly should I put dbfile to be accessed from visual studio project, and is it ok to use this Environment.CurrentDirectory directory in production code, if yes where should be stored in production.

Comment: I'd advise against mixing read only/read-write resources in one directory in general. CurrentDirectory can be anything, even something unrelared to where your application lives. If you want to have it dynamic, why not place it in the "configuration"

Comment: Agree with the answers that it's not a good choice. Pick any shortcut on your machine. Look at its properties. Note that the "Start in" value will affect the initial current directory for that program - and is completely independent from the path to that program - so there's no relationship there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good choice of folder.

If you want a path specific to a user, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`.

If you want a path specific to the application, then `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or `Application.StartupPath` are worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` is the directory from where your application is started. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) for more info.

I wouldn't rely on it for production though.